# Surface groups and non separating loops

Tags: gr.group-theory, mapping-class-groups, geometric-group-theory

QUESTION: Let $g \geq 4$, $S(g)$ be the fundamental group of the genus $g$ surface, and $G$ be  finitely generated (the number of generators $\leq 3$) group with abelianization of rank less than equal $2$. Assume that there exist a surjection $\phi: S(g) \rightarrow G$. Is it true that the kernel of $\phi$ contains at least one non separating loop of the surface? If it is any helpful, you can assume $G$ is a perfect group.

Answer (score 6):

The Simple Loop Conjecture is as follows.

> Every non-injective map from a surface group to a 3-manifold group kills a simple closed curve.

As there are all sorts of 3-manifolds with abelianisation of rank two, I think the answer to your question is unknown.

**UPDATE:** Sorry, I wrote the above too hastily.  I should have said 'I think that the kernel is not known to contain such a loop.'  On the other hand, there may well be examples of such maps with no simple loops in the kernel.  You could try looking at Louder's recent preprint on the [Simple loop conjecture for limit groups](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1350), for instance.

Comment: Thanks! Are there cases of $3$-manifolds (with infinite $\pi_1)$) for which we know Simple Loop Conjecture holds? Would it be helpful if we assume that the group $G$ has three (or less) generators and abelianization of rank 0. 

Comment: @Thom - The simple loop conjecture holds for three-manifolds of the form surface cross interval, by work of Gabai. 

Comment: A quick search of MathSciNet shows that the Simple Loop Conjecture holds for Seifert-fibred 3-manifolds and, more generally, graph manifolds.  As there are very complicated hyperbolic 3-manifolds with trivial H_1 and two generators, I would be surprised if those assumptions help much. 

Comment: Thanks Henry! I am convinced that the answer to my question is unknown. 

Comment: @Henry: The question in fact has nothing to do with 3-manifolds. What one needs is to kill long and complicated self-intersecting loops and at the same time kill the first homology by imposing relations of the form $x=$ long commutator where $x$ is a standard generator of the surface group. The goal is to produce a quotient with no simple loops in the kernel. I think it is quite doable and the example should exist. I am not sure now about the number of generators ($\le 3$) of the quotient, but that also should be possible to achieve with some effort. 

Comment: Mark - yes, I'm aware of that.  If you look at the UPDATE in my answer, you'll see that I assert that 'there may well be examples of such maps with no simple loops in the kernel'.  I also suggest somewhere to look for examples.